# list taxonomies from a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I registered a Taxonomy for a custom post type called events.

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function events_categories() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'events_categories', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'events_category', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Kategorien', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'query_var'                  => true
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'events_category', array( 'events' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'events_categories', 0 );
```

I want to display the taxonomies like this, but iam getting an error ( invalid taxonomy )

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'events_category',
    'hide_empty' => false
) );

echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $terms );
echo '</pre>';
```

EDIT:
This is the custom post type

```
// Register Custom Post Type - Veranstaltungen
// Register Custom Post Type
function leweb_events_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Events', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Event', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Events', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Event', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Event', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Veranstaltungen von Besuchern', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'revisions', 'custom-fields' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'events_category'),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-page',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'events', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'leweb_events_post_type', 0 );
```

Comment: You've registered the taxonomy as `events_category`, so you need to use that in the `get_terms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out a solution by myself. 
It seems that this particular code needs to be in the loop - So it works now, the OP Code is correct then...

Answer (score 0):

In your code you’re using this to register taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy( 'events_category', array( 'events' ), $args );
```

So the taxonomy is called `events_category`.

And in `get_terms` you use `events_categories`.

Here’s the fixed getting terms part:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'events_category',
    'hide_empty' => false
) );
```

Comment: i fixed the spelling problem, but i doesnt work :-(

Comment: @LovinQuaQua and how is your CPT registered?

Comment: I added it to the OP

Comment: do you have an idea?